# How to wait to append the data until after the form data has been added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events

When I click the `#screenrId`, it submits the default data without having time to add the new data the user inputs. How to wait to append the data until after the form input field data has been added?

http://jsfiddle.net/XVCVE/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {      
    Screenr.Recorder( { subject:""}).appendTo("screenrId");        
});        
</script>     
<form>    
    <h4>Subject <input name="subject" id='subject' type="text" ></h4>
</form>
<div id="screenrId" ></div>
```

I am trying to add the form data to the `screen.recorder` function before it appends it? `Screenr.Recorder( { subject:""})`.

Comment: could you please help us out with a sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think I fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/XVCVE/3/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I just fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/XVCVE/3/

The problems:

1. The "javascript" section in jsfiddle assumes raw javascript, no `<script>` tags, so I moved that code to the top.
2. You had a very strange way to make sure the correct HTTP protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) was used to load the 3rd party library, when the browser will do that automatically if you just *don't write* the `http:` or `https:`.

After that, the button appeared after a slight delay.

Comment: how do i add the form input data to the screen.recorder({subject:""})appendTo("ScreenerId");

Comment: What do you mean? Append the form data in what way to what?

Comment: the button is appearing in my browser, just not in jfiddle. that was not the issue. when the user inputs the subject field, and presses the button to call the screen recorder, how do i add this form field data the user inputs, to the screen.recorder function before the screen recorder is called?

Comment: Can you show me the API documentation for this Screen Recorder object? I've never run into it before, but the answer is probably in there.

Comment: david, thanks for your help. that is a great idea. the api doc is here http://business.screenr.com/api/launching-recorder.php

Comment: Okay, now I understand your problem. The answer is simple: your ``<div>`` needs to be *inside* of the ``<form>`` tag to act as a submit button for that form element.

Comment: i am not sure how placing the div screenr id inside the form will help achieve what i need. the form is not functional. it is not really necessary for their to be a form element, since the form value is not being submitted. the value of the input element needs to be gotten using javascript, on click of the screenr.id button, and then inserted into the sreeenr.record function.

Comment: Sorry, found another page on the API: http://business.screenr.com/api/settings.php You need to get a reference to the ``recorder`` object and call the ``setSubject`` method, perhaps using something like ``$('#subject').on('change', function() { ...``